# uniqueness of Lagrange multipliers in linear programming

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

Let max $c^Tx$  s.t. $Ax\leq b$ be a LP problem.

(a) If  the primal problem has a unique solution, will the dual problem also have a unique solution?

(b) If the primal problem has infinitely many solutions, when will the dual problem have a unique solution?

Thanks.

Comment: The duality theorem says one of four cases will occur: (1) normal case: both the primal and dual have an optimal solution: max cTx = min yTb, (2) the primal has no feasible solution x but the dual has feasible solutions with yTb going to negative infinity, (3) the dual has no feasible solutions with cTx going to infinity, and (4) neither primal nor dual has a feasible solution.

Comment: @AndrewGray the question is about uniqueness in the "normal case".

Comment: Ok sure.  In that case, the answer to (a) is YES.  If primal has unique solution then so does the dual.